# How see which github repository is connected to heroku app?

Tags: heroku

How can you see the code for an app, or link to its github repository if all you have is the app's name (i.e. url)?

The reason for asking is I have a few apps and I'm not sure which repositories they link to (some are very similar - if I can inspect the codebases, I can be sure which one's which)

Answer (score 0):

Within the folder where the app is stored, there is a hidden folder called **.git**. Note the unusual leading dot; it's really there. Given that, and assuming that you have the command line Git client installed on your machine, do the following.

1. Open the Windows Explorer.
2. On Options dialog, ensure that the option to show **hidden** files is *enabled*.
3. Navigate to the folder that contains the app in question.
4. Open a command prompt in that window. The easiest way to do that is to click in the address box, and overtype the folder path with the word "cmd."
5. In the command prompt window that opens, enter **git remote show origin**.

The foregoing produces a report that looks like the following.

```
F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\_Laboratory\JSON_Jam 2019/05/25 14:38:27.98>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/txwizard/JSON_Jam.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/txwizard/JSON_Jam.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

F:\Source_Code\Visual_Studio\Projects\_Laboratory\JSON_Jam 2019/05/25 14:38:32.21>
```

The **Fetch URL** and **Push URL**, which are usually the same, contain the information that you need, which will look something like **https://github.com/txwizard/JSON_Jam.git**.

In the above URL, **txwizard** is my GitHub login ID, and **JSON_Jam** is the repository name.

If Windows doesn't recognize the command, you may need to install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). When you run the installation program, tell it that you want the command line tools, and that you want it integrated with the native command processor, **cmd.exe**.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt window navigate to directory where your project is located and enter `git remote -v`